# In Octave, how do you source a file if the file name is stored in a variable?

Tags: octave

I feel like this must be very easy, but I can't find the answer anywhere.  In octave (and probably matlab but I haven't verified), you can source the contents of a file by doing

```
source /path/to/filename
```

However, let's say I have the filename stored in a variable called file.  If you do `source file`, it treats `file` as the path rather than what is stored in file.  I have tried inserting `eval` in various places but if that is the answer, I haven't found the correct invocation.  I don't know much octave; there is surely a trivial answer to this that I am overlooking?

Comment: `>> help source  source not found.`

`7.14.0.739 (R2012a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about octave, but try to use a function call

```
source(fname)
```

That's what you do in matlab at least.

Comment: The reason for this: `source filename` is actually interpreted as `source('filename')`.

Comment: This works. I knew there had to be some easy way to do it, but it is not documented (at least in octave 3.6)